# How to "expand" a SQL join such that each unique value in column A "get" all the unique values for B?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a dataset with two columns: id and date. The dates are monthly and span from Mar-21 to Aug-21. I am sure this question could be applied to non-date values, but I think dates are more intuitive for this example.

```
 id | date   |
----+--------+--
 a  | Mar-21 | 
 a  | Apr-21 | 
 a  | Aug-21 | <---- 'a' is missing Jun-21 and Jul-21
 b  | Mar-21 | 
 b  | May-21 | <---- 'b' is missing Apr-21
 b  | Jun-21 | 
 b  | Jul-21 | 
 b  | Aug-21 |
```

And I want this

```
 id | date   |
----+--------+--
 a  | Mar-21 | 
 a  | Apr-21 | 
 a  | May-21 | 
 a  | Jun-21 | <---- 'a' gets Jun-21 
 a  | Aug-21 | <---- ...and now Jul-21
 b  | Mar-21 | 
 b  | Apr-21 | <---- 'b' gets Apr-21
 b  | May-21 | 
 b  | Jun-21 | 
 b  | Jul-21 | 
 b  | Aug-21 |
```

Basically I want to say "I want every single `id` to get all unique values of `date`.

Comment: Do you mean you want one record for every month? In that case you might want to use a calandar table

Answer (score 2):

Consider below approach

```
select id, format_date('%b-%y', dt) date 
from unnest(generate_date_array('2021-03-01', '2021-08-01', interval 1 month)) dt,
(select distinct id from your_table)
-- order by id, dt
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]